# MS SQL server 2019 failover cluster - Event ID 18456, Login failed for user 'domain\server1$'

Tags: sql-server, failovercluster, windows-cluster, service-accounts

New MS SQL server 2019 installation on Windows Server 2019, failover cluster role enabled; fully patched Windows, SQL 2019 CU 11.

Nodes:
**server1** - 10.10.10.1
**server2** - 10.10.10.2

Instances:
**sql1**
**sql2**

The instances were initially installed: **sql1** on **server1**, **sql2** on **server2**, clustered install. **sql1** and **sql2** do failover smoothly, everything works as expected.

The problem is a seemingly harmful event on Windows Logs -> Application (Event ID `18456`):

```
Login failed for user 'domain\server1$'. Reason: Could not find a login matching the name provided. [CLIENT: 10.10.10.1]
```

and

```
Login failed for user domain\server2$. Reason: Could not find a login matching the name provided. [CLIENT: 10.10.10.2]
```

The events are produced when **sql1** is moved to **server2** and **sql2** is moved to **server1**. It seems that there is some kind of record on each instance with the server that was installed initially and is searching for it. No issues apart from the annoying message.

I've searched the Net a lot, tried the suggestions about disabling CEIP telemetry, disabled sql services one by one to locate the one producing the event (sql server produces it), added the NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE to logins, sysadmin on both **sql1** & **sql2**. No effect. Any ideas?

---

It seems that `domain\server1$` is a service account - virtual account. In the initial sql instances installation some services where started by non-domain accounts (default suggestion). But now all services start using domain accounts, yet the event is still produced.

Comment: `It seems that domain\server1$ is a service account`. It's the computer account. In AD the computer account samAccountName is suffixed with $.

Comment: @GregAskew, it is, but I cannot locate any record of it, where it's used. I just get the event.

Comment: Nearly all Windows hosts use their AD machine account for authentication. May be a transient recoverable condition created by the failover.